# How do i get a href value from a link inside li list?

Tags: jquery

Here is a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nLyqA/)

I want to get the `href` attribute, I use `$(this).attr('href')` but it does not work!

**HTML**  :

```
<div class="wrap_atletas_interno">
    <ul>
        <li class="atleta">
            <a href="teste.html">
                <div class="nome_86_atleta">Antônio</div>
                <img src="atletas/antonio_86px.jpg" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li  class="atleta">
            <div class="nome_86_atleta">Cauê</div>
            <img src="atletas/caue_86px.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li class="atleta">
            <div class="nome_86_atleta">Dudu</div>
            <img src="atletas/dudu_86px.jpg" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript** :

```
$('.atleta').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.atleta').removeClass('atleta_atual');
    $(this).addClass('atleta_atual');
    var h = $(this).attr('href');
    alert(h);
    $.get(h, function (data) {
        //$(".detalhes_atleta").html(data).fadeIn("slow");
        alert(h);
    });
});
```

Comment: `var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');`

Comment: `$(this).children('a').attr('href')`. Also typo at `altert(h)`;

Comment: `DIV` is not a valid child of `<A>` , markup is invalid

Comment: yeah.. sorry my wrong typo!.. .ty all!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Check the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLyqA/2/)

Changed

```
var h = $("a",this).attr('href');
```

Answer (score 4):

`$(this)` is referring to the parent `li` of the link. You need to use

```
$(this).find('a').attr('href');
```

Also please fix your `html`, block elements should not be inside inline elements.

In your case the `div` should not be in the `a`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var h = $('a', this).attr('href');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this instead

```
     var href= $('a',this).length>0? $('a',this).attr('href') : '';
```

Answer (score 1):

here, `$this` is pointing to the `<li>` but u need the `href` attr of `<a>` so find `<a>` inside `<li>` and get the attr `href`...

try this

```
$(this).find('a').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the `href` attribute from `a`, but `$(this)` in your example is for the `li` , that is why it is not working.

Why not set the click event on the `a` instead ?

Example: `$('.atleta a').click(function(e) ...`